# My Azure functions just crashes (former: Can not find the source failure for my not responding Function app)

Tags: azure, runtime-error

I have a function app which sometimes fails (it happened 4 times in 1 month, 2 of which were in the last 3 days).

I tried investigating, but I'm not sure where to look.

This is what I see for the function

[image]

[image]

and no failing requests:

[image]

So it looks like everything is running.
Then I looked at my functions: functions inaccessible
[image]

and a call to the function:
[image]

And this error doesn't look good too:

[image]

The last thing which doesn't look good is this, it is from the storage:

[image]

and this one

[image]

So I found a lot of errors (in that chart) on my storage, but I can't figure out where they come from.
There is nothing to click on from the chart.

I've clicked every monitor and health check, but the only errors I've found are on storage, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I don't know if I understand that the function app stops when there is an error on the storage it communicates with. But on first sight the function app shows all green indicators, only after I click around in the function app subpages, then after a few clicks it seems to understand that it is in error.

---

### EDIT: same thing happened today at march 10

Now I've found a clear error. Seems like a kind of DI exception.
Weird thing is, it is running for 22 days (getting called every 5 minutes so 288 times a day) and then boom it stops. And not once, but it crashes, the host stops and the whole function just stops.

```
 The function runtime is unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: Assembly with same name is already loaded.


 System.IO.FileLoadException : Assembly with same name is already loaded

  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext,String ilPath,String niPath,ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)

  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.b__0(AssemblyName assemblyName) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\DependencyInjection\ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 116

  at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String asmName,Func`2 assemblyResolver,Boolean throwOnError,StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

  at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver,Func`4 typeResolver,Boolean throwOnError,Boolean ignoreCase,StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

  at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName,Func`2 assemblyResolver,Func`4 typeResolver,Boolean throwOnError,Boolean ignoreCase,StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

  at System.Type.GetType(String typeName,Func`2 assemblyResolver,Func`4 typeResolver,Boolean throwOnError,Boolean ignoreCase)

  at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetExtensionsStartupTypesAsync() at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\DependencyInjection\ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 113

  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetStartupTypes() at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\DependencyInjection\ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 55

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalStartup(IWebJobsBuilder builder,IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator startupTypeLocator,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs : 167

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.UseScriptExternalStartup(IWebJobsBuilder builder,ScriptApplicationHostOptions applicationHostOptions,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,IExtensionBundleManager extensionBundleManager,IMetricsLogger metricsLogger) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 237

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context,IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 114

  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WebJobsHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__1(HostBuilderContext context,IServiceCollection services) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 47

  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()

  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DefaultScriptHostBuilder.BuildHost(Boolean skipHostStartup,Boolean skipHostConfigurationParsing) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DefaultScriptHostBuilder.cs : 59

  at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebJobsScriptHostService.UnsynchronizedStartHostAsync(ScriptHostStartupOperation activeOperation,Int32 attemptCount,JobHostStartupMode startupMode) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\WebJobsScriptHostService.cs : 234
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same "The function runtime is unable to start. System.Private.CoreLib: Assembly with same name is already loaded." error occasionally.  I had it on two separate functions over the weekend.

I see this error in pink error box within the UI.  You can find the stack trace for this under Platform Features -> Diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and reporting -> Function App Down or Reporting Errors.

Apparently the reason I get "Assembly with same name is already loaded" is a rare condition caused by the cold start optimisation. The WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER setting instructs the platform to run your code on a worker with the functions runtime already loaded. This reduces the duration of cold start. If not specified the default is WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER=1.

Setting WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER=0 turns this off.

Comment: I was not smart enough to write down where in the maze of logging I found this. I'm not sure If I found this in the app insights or in the diagnose part (at your function, go to tab platform features, then diagnose and solve problems, then 5.xx features.). I did once go to the live metrics stream. When it will re-occur (I'm afraid it will) I will add this.

Comment: I btw also had an offline app this weekend because of an Azure platform update. Couldn't find where that went wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats where I found it ... eventually.  I raised this with Microsoft and got a satisfactory workaround. which I'll put in my answer.

Comment: Is the WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER a setting I should apply in the `application settings` in the configuration of the function app?

Comment: Yes that's right. Setting is documented here - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings